# Format foreach macros the same as loops with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have a `foreach` style macro, similar to `BOOST_FOREACH`, that I would like to be formatted similarly to the below:

```
int bar(int a) { return ++a; }

int bar(int a) {
  a += 2;
  return ++a;
}

int foo(std::vector<int> a) {
  BOOST_FOREACH (auto i, a) {
    ++i;
  }

  for (auto &i : a) {
    ++i;
  }

  BOOST_FOREACH (auto i, a) {
    ++i;
    i += 2;
  }

  for (auto &i : a) {
    ++i;
    i += 2;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the LLVM style that I'm using as a base does this:

```
  BOOST_FOREACH (auto i, a) { ++i; }

  BOOST_FOREACH (auto i, a) {
    ++i;
    i += 2;
  }
```

i.e. puts short/single line `foreach` macro loop bodies onto a single line, although it doesn't do this to normal `for` loops.

I cannot find a `clang-format` option that . Here's what I've tried, starting with the LLVM style as a base:

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:   
  AfterControlStatement: true
```

gives:

```
  BOOST_FOREACH (auto i, a)
  { ++i; }

  for (auto &i : a)
  {
    ++i;
  }
```

which looks like it's maybe a bug?

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:   
  AfterFunction: true
```

is almost what I want, but it obviously also affects functions, which I don't want:

```
int foo(std::vector<int> a)
{
  BOOST_FOREACH (auto i, a) {
    ++i;
  }
...
```

Putting

```
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
```

only affects the one-line `bar` and not the `foreach` macros, so I don't think it's because `clang-format` is seeing the macro as a function definition.

Am I missing something, or is this a possible bug in `clang-format`?

Comment: Does your `.clang-format` contain `ForEachMacros:   [ BOOST_FOREACH ]`?

Comment: @Zeta Yep, all this after editing `clang-format -style=LLVM -dump-config > .clang-format`, which includes that line, and with `clang-format` 6.0.0

Comment: Did you try `AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: 'false'` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're missing anything. I agree it looks like a bug in `clang-format`.

The `AfterControlStatement` setting doesn't work correctly when formatting the `BOOST_FOREACH` loop, and `AfterFunction` affects it but really should not. For me, the `ForEachMacros` setting isn't working at all, and this might be part of the problem (the behavior is identical when I remove `BOOST_FOREACH` from the list of for-each macros).